# Zusammenhang zwischen "Rappen" und "berappen"?

Tags: colloquial, swiss-german

Hat denn die kleinste schweizerische Währungseinheit "der Rappen" etwas mit dem Verb "berappen" (ugs. für *bezahlen*) zu tun?

Ich finde für beide Wörter sehr vage und auch teilweise stark voneinander abweichende Herkunftsvermutungen.

Answer (score 10):

Im *Etymologischen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* (Der Kluge, 23. Aufl. 1995) steht zu *berappen* (S. 98):

> **berappen** *swV. stil.* ‚bezahlen‘ (< 19. Jh.).
>   Das Wort ist aus der Studentensprache in die Hochsprache gelangt;
>   dorthin kam es offenbar aus schwäbischen Krämersprachen, also Ausprägungen des Rotwelschen.
>   Die weitere Herkunft ist unklar: Sowohl gegen die Ableitung von der Scheidemünze *Rappen* wie auch gegen Anknüpfungen an das Jiddische und Hebräische können starke Bedenken geltend gemacht werden.
>   Nach Wolf aus *berabbeln*, dieses aus *berebbeln*, *beribbeln* zu *Rebbes* „Zins, Gewinn, Ertrag“.
>   Nach Buttenwieser aus hebr. *j<sup>e</sup>rappē* „(Heilung) bezahlen“ umgeformt (vgl. *Exod.* 21,19).
>   Buttenwieser *ZD* 36 (1922), 181—183;
>   S. A. Birnbaum *ZDPh* 74 (1955), 249;
>   Wolf (1985), 264;
>   Röhrich 1 (1991), 172.

Zu *Rappen* findet sich hingegen (S. 667):

> **Rappen** *m. erw. fach.* „kleine Münze“, heute *schwz*. (< 14 Jh.).
>   Währungseinheit des Rappenmünzbundes (alemannisch) im 15./16. Jh.
>   Zuerst bezeugt *Kolmar-Rappen* vom 14. Jh.
>   Vielleicht ursprünglich scherzhafte Bezeichnung der schlechten Pfennig-Prägungen eines Herrn von Rappoltstein mit Anspielung auf den Adler des Münzbildes – *Rappen* ist Nebenform zu *Rappe*<sup>1</sup> in dessen ursprünglicher Bedeutung „Rabe“.

Wir haben also zwei Wörter mit unterschiedlichen Ursprüngen:

1. *berappen*: Hebr. *j<sup>e</sup>rappē* (etwa in der Bibel)
2. *Rappen*: über *Rappe*<sup>1</sup> (schwarzes Pferd) zu *Rabe* (vgl. *Kluge, S. 663): Mhd. *raben*, ahdt. *(h)raban*, mndd. *raven* aus g. * *hrabna- m* (mit weiteren Nebenformen, *rappo* etc.): * *kra-p-no-* „der *kra* (macht)“.

Ob diese Herleitungen korrekt sind, kann ich nicht beurteilen.
Sogar im Kluge wird die Herkunft von *berappen* aus dem Hebräischen angezweifelt, ohne jedoch weiter darauf einzugehen.

Answer (score 5):

Die Grimms leiten das Wort [berappen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR00741#XGR00741) in der Bedeutung von Bezahlen wie folgt her:

> **rappen** in **berappen**, eine Wand mit Putz bewerfen; in derber neuerer Rede davon etwas berappen, Geld für etwas hinwerfen, bezahlen; seine Zeche berappen; auch den Wirt, den Schneider berappen (ohne Zusammenhang mit der Münze Rappe)

Ein Zusammenhang mit der Münze Rappe wird dort also explizit verneint. Auch im [Schweizerischen Idiotikon](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id6.htm#!page/61181/mode/1up) wird eine Etymologie vom Rappenmünzbund nicht gesehen:

> Die fremde Herkunft zeigt sich in der Form des Präfixes.

Damit ist auch erklärt, warum das Verb außerhalb des Währungsraums des Rappens vorkommt.